# How to specify time for youtube api in ruby

Tags: ruby, api, youtube

I'm writing Ruby script to communicate with [Youtube Streaming API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#resource) to create live stream and live broadcast. So far, I have been able to write code to insert new stream and it works but I'm facing problem while inserting broadcast. I'm getting the following error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/google-api-client-0.8.0/lib/google/api_client.rb:652:in `block (2 levels) in execute!': Scheduled start time is required (Google::APIClient::ClientError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/retriable-1.4.1/lib/retriable/retry.rb:27:in `perform'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/retriable-1.4.1/lib/retriable.rb:15:in `retriable'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/google-api-client-0.8.0/lib/google/api_client.rb:635:in `block in execute!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/retriable-1.4.1/lib/retriable/retry.rb:27:in `perform'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/retriable-1.4.1/lib/retriable.rb:15:in `retriable'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/google-api-client-0.8.0/lib/google/api_client.rb:626:in `execute!'
    from ruby_script.rb:44:in `insert_broadcast'
    from ruby_script.rb:98:in `<main>'
```

So, its complaining that I haven't mentioned the scheduled start time. Here's the relevant code:

```
# Create a liveBroadcast resource and set its title, scheduled start time,
# scheduled end time, and privacy status.
def insert_broadcast(client, youtube, options)
  insert_broadcast_response = client.execute!(
    api_method: youtube.live_broadcasts.insert,
    parameters: {
      part: 'snippet,status'
    },
    body_object: {
      snippet: {
        title: options[:broadcast_title],
        scheduledStartTime: options[:state_time],
        scheduledEndTime: options[:end_time]
      },
      status: {
        privacyStatus: options[:privacy_status]
      }
    }
  )

  p "Broadcast: #{insert_broadcast_response.data.id}"
  return insert_broadcast_response.id
end

options = {
  stream_title: 'stream',
  broadcast_title: 'dumdum',
  start_time: '2018-01-30T00:00:00.000Z',
  end_time: '2018-01-30T00:01:00.000Z',
  privacy_status: 'private'
}
```

The format of date time I have borrowed from [this](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/create_broadcast.py) code sample which is in Python. I tried with `start_time: Time.now` hoping Ruby date time object might work but it didn't. How do I solve this?

**Edit**: [Here's](https://gist.github.com/lokeshh/0bc65780c9bf55c58b2b41fc63db4aa6) the complete script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you have `scheduledStartTime: options[:state_time],` and are passing it into the method as `options[:start_time]`

Comment: That was the issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Fix the typo as per @Simple-Lime's answer, and if its still doesn't work try the following:

You need to format your time correctly:
`Time.now` output is `2017-07-27 07:35:38 +0000` which is wrong.
You need to change it to datetime format of ISO-8601 standard with decimal notation of the timezone with [`Time#iso8601`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-i-iso8601):

```
require 'time'

# example time format: '2014-01-30T00:00:00.000Z'
Time.now.getutc.iso8601(3)
# => "2017-07-27T07:30:33.742Z"
```

Comment: @Lokesh Updated my answer. try it now.

Comment: Did u fix the state_time typo like he mentioned? And are you actually passing the options into your function when you run it?

Comment: Just saw it now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It provides a nice way to mention the pass the date rather than as a string.